# Product boxes with the same width and height, despite the size of the images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create cards for different products, and the idea is that they should be all the same size in all directions, independent from the original size of the images, but now all the images are exceeding the limits that I thought I had placed.

Also, I started studying HTML and CSS about two weeks ago, so, sorry if it's just a simple thing.

[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9Cg.png)

```css
#products-btn{
 outline: none;
 border-radius: 18px;
 background: transparent;
 border:2px solid black;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 60%;
 height: 45px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 10px;
}

#products-btn:hover{
 background-color:black;
 color: white; 
}

#products-btn:active{
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#products{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 text-align: center;

}

#cards{
 display: inline-block;
 border:1px solid black;
 max-width: 250px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 box-shadow: 2px 0 3px 4px #ccc;
}

#cards:not(:last-child){
 margin-right: 20px;
}

/*#cards img{
 border:1px solid black;
}  
*/
```

```html
<div id="products">
  
     <div id="cards" class="Product1">
      <img src="images/products/img1.jpg">
      <h1>Travel 1</h1>
      <p class="price">$240.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product one -->

     <div id="cards" class="Product2">
      <img src="images/products/img2.jpg">
      <h1>Travel 2</h1>
      <p class="price">$300.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product two -->
      

     <div id="cards" class="Product3">
      <img src="images/products/img3.jpg">
      <h1>Travel 3</h1>
      <p class="price">$280.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product three -->
     
    
    </div><!-- products container -->
```

Comment: upload your images https://imgbb.com/ here and update code with image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some changes to fit your images to the size you want. Like seen below.

Please also not, don't use `#cards` as id -- IDs must be globally unique so it doesn't make sense to be an ID. The same applies for your other ID values (e.g. buttons, and similar).

```css
#products-btn{
 outline: none;
 border-radius: 18px;
 background: transparent;
 border:2px solid black;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 60%;
 height: 45px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 10px;
}

#products-btn:hover{
 background-color:black;
 color: white; 
}

#products-btn:active{
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#products{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 text-align: center;

}

.cards{
 display: inline-block;
 border:1px solid black;
 max-width: 250px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 box-shadow: 2px 0 3px 4px #ccc;
}

.cards:not(:last-child){
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.product-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

/*#cards img{
 border:1px solid black;
}  
*/
```

```html
<div id="products">
  
     <div class="cards Product1">
            <div class="product-img" style="background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/300');"></div>
      <h1>Travel 1</h1>
      <p class="price">$240.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product one -->

     <div class="cards Product2">
            <div class="product-img" style="background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/800/300');"></div>
      <h1>Travel 2</h1>
      <p class="price">$300.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product two -->
      

     <div class="cards Product3">
            <div class="product-img" style="background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/800');"></div>
      <h1>Travel 3</h1>
      <p class="price">$280.00</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat lectus vitae risus.</p>
      <p><button id="products-btn">Travel now!</button></p>
     </div><!-- product three -->
     
    
    </div><!-- products container -->
```

Comment: I tried and it also works, thanks a lot for the help. And I will be more careful with IDs and classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the image a maximum width of 100%. Then it can not exceed the maximum size of his parent div.

```css
#cards img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

By the way, you should also focus on the usage of classes and ids. A class can be used on multiple elements on a page. But an id should only be used on one element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the warning about the ids. Everything is working now and i've changed the ids to classes.

Answer (score 0):

hi can you try by applying css to image as i shown below this works correct

```
img{
max-width: 250px;
max-height: 300px;
}
```

here is the image [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add image width in css as

```
img{
    width : 250px;
}
```